# Why does the C64's LIST command choke on REM statements with a Shift+L?

Tags: commodore-64, basic, vic-20

On the Commodore 64 and VIC-20, the `LIST` command will abort with a `?SYNTAX  ERROR` on any line that contains a `REM` statement with a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> character.  A minimal program triggering the error would look as follows:

```
10 rem L
```

Some programmers deliberately started or peppered their BASIC programs with such "killer `REM`" statements to hide the source code.  (Of course, the protection this provided was only rudimentary, and could be easily bypassed.)

As far as I know, this quirk affects only the C64 and VIC-20; the C128, C16, Plus/4, and various PET models don't care about the argument of `REM` statements. What I don't understand is *why* this quirk exists and how it works.  Is this a bug or a feature of CBM BASIC?  If it's a feature, was it ever documented anywhere by Commodore, and why is it present only on the C64 and VIC-20?  If it's a bug, what exactly causes the `LIST` command to choke on a shifted `L` in a `REM` statement?

Comment: It also affects the CBM 8032, all the way down to the PET 2001.

Comment: @cup On my PET emulation running BASIC 4, it results in a listing in which the `shift`-`l` is replaced by `CONCAT` i.e. `10 REM CONCAT`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why this quirk exists and how it works.

As usual, lousy programming. It's a routine that exists in next to every Microsoft Basic, but often modified by the receiving company. It's used to list a line. On the 6502 version space was a premium, so they tried to cut down as much as possible in tests. And lets be serious, a 'real' terminal can not produce codes above 128 so there is no chance someone would enter a token code somewhere. And what computer engineer in his right mind would create a machine using other codes than plain ASCII?

> Is this a bug or a feature of CBM BASIC?

It's a combination of several little bits of 'less than perfect' ending up creating a bug.

> and why is it present only on the C64 and VIC-20?

Because here the token table is exact 127 bytes of token names plus one byte of zero.

> If it's a bug, what exactly causes the LIST command to choke on a shifted L in a `REM` statement?

As described already, the list routine iterates over all program lines and in each it displays the line number and then parses all token/text and print it. Tokens are recognized by having the high bit set. Tokens on the C64 reach from $80 (`END`) to $CA (`GO`) plus $FF for `PI`. Whenever a token is detected, the token table is searched for (`PI` is handled separately) in the most primitive way: $7F is subtracted and then tokens are scanned and skipped with that value decremented until zero is reached. Then this word pointing at is printed. Not really fast, but who cares during listing.This all works fine and stable - even with unused tokens. Try enter a <kbd>Shift + M</kbd>, and you get a `FOR` ($81) listed.

Just $CB fails, as it points to the combination of a single zero and an 128 Byte overflow.

In conclusion it's a combination of a missing upper boundary check together with an addressing problem that only appears when using a character set not designed for and an input routine not catching it either.

The original routine can be found in all MS-Basic 1.0. For newer MS-Basics the token table is of a different length and the routine is modified - usually by using a 16 Bit Pointer instead of a fixed address plus offset - as their token tables are larger than 127 bytes.

Comment: I have seen this used in C64 Text Adventure games to hide the answers to riddles.

Comment: There's still something unexplained: why do you need `REM` to trigger the bug? The same character in other places doesn't do the same thing. (And other graphic characters don't expand into tokens either)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Because these  ("_at other places_") characters are all part of strings, which are handled different (when ever a `"` is encountered, characters are direct outputed until the next `"`).

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but an essential detail of your answer is incorrect. The length of the token text table is irrelevant.

Comment: @RhialtosupportsMonica It's your opinion and your choice if you think negative feedback is more important than positive or staying neutral. Be my guest.

Comment: @Raffzahn It seems my reputation is too low still for it to count, anyway. But it was because I knew that the assertion about the length of the token text table could not be right (since the issue exists in Basic versions with more and with fewer keywords), that I went to find out what the real cause is.

Answer (score 29):

Internally, a BASIC program isn't represented as the text you see when you list it, but as a [tokenized data structure](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/BASIC_token) where each of the language keywords are represented in an optimized 1-character form. Basically, if the upper bit is set in a character byte (i.e. values >= 128/$80), it is processed as a token.

Note that this does not only apply to the shift-L case, fx entering `"10 REM` <kbd>Shift + A</kbd>`"` will list as `"10 REM ATN"`. If you consult a list of the predefined [BASIC tokens](http://sta.c64.org/cbm64basins2.html), you will find that 203/$CB is the last defined; this will match <kbd>Shift + K</kbd>. After this, you are presumably (I'm speculating, haven't actually pored over the ROM listing) referencing a non existing or otherwise erroneous token, and the interpreter bails.

That you can enter tokens directly would seem like a bug or at least design limitation that was found acceptable, but I've never seen any official stance on that. Earliest mention of this token quirk I could find was in a [1983 issue of Compute!](http://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue38/087_1_COMMODORE_REM_REVEALED.php).

Comment: The shift key sets the 0x80 bit in the character on this system?  (As opposed to its usual function with alphabetics, of selecting upper case versus lower case)

Comment: @another-dave Yes, it does. Find a picture of the first model PET and this is most clear. Later ones muddle the issue by rearranging the keys.

Comment: The shift key does both! If you look at the upper/lowercase PETSCII chart, you will see that the uppercase characters appear _twice_ – once starting at decimal 97/$61 where ASCII has the lowercase letters, and again starting at 193/$C1, which is just the uppercase letters down at 65/$41 with the high bit set. And if you ask any Commodore computer for the ASC() value of one of those characters, it will report the high-bit value. So the shift key really is a high-bit-toggle key from the PETSCII standpoint, at least for letters and with the original PET keyboard for other characters as well.

Answer (score 12):

The answer by @Raffzahn is close, but it has at least one important detail wrong: the total length of the token names has nothing to do with it.

The following facts all all relate to the issue.

- Commodore Basic (any Microsoft Basic really) stores programs in a tokenized form in memory. That means here that all Basic keywords are replaced by a single byte, and other text is stored as `PETSCII` (Commodore's variant of ASCII).
- The token values start at $80 (0x80).
- In particular on the first PETs, there is a very strong relationship between the PETSCII value of a key and its shifted variant. Pressing shift adds $80. On later models, keyboards have been rearranged, and this connection is much less clear (but the character encoding has not changed).
- Text that follows the REM statement is just copied into the program, without tokenizing, but also without checking if it is pure text.
- Normally, bytes of $80 and higher that are meant to be text are only allowed in string denotations. When `LIST`ing, strings are treated separately from non-strings.
- The first version of Basic allowed spaces in keywords while tokenizing. So if you write `GO TO 10`, this gets tokenized the same way as `GOTO 10`.
- This led to problems for instance with the statement `IF ST AND 64 THEN`..., which gets tokenized as `IF S TAN D 64 THEN`... which is of course a syntax error.
- The second version did not allow the spaces any more. But apparently it was deemed important that people could still write `GO TO 10`, so an extra keyword `GO` was added. `TO` already existed: `FOR I=1 TO 10:`...
- Now it was discovered that if you used the new `GO` keyword on a computer with the *newer* Basic and transported it to the *older* version, you would get the `?SYNTAX ERROR` when listing the program there.
- The token value of `GO` is 203 (75 + 128 or shift-K).
- The reason was that the `GO` token was (there) just 1 past the allowed tokens (for that Basic version).
- The same problem exists on the *new* version, just with a token value 1 higher: 204, aka 76 + 128, aka shift-L.
- The VIC-20 and the Commodore 64 both use this version, substantially unchanged.
- This shows that the total length of the token strings being some magic value is NOT the cause of the problem: in the two BASIC variants, this total differs.
- The problem also exists for an even later version of Basic (BASIC 4.0 with disk management keywords added). Here the problematic value is 219 (91 + 128, or shift-[). Unfortunately, on keyboards of emulators, or the ones supplied with the PET model 8032, this is difficult or impossible to type. But if you enter a program `10 REM X` and then `POKE 1031,219` (which overwrites the `X`, if you didn't add anything extra), you can see the effect.

So what *does* cause the problem?

- The full text of the tokens is stored sequentially, in numeric order. The last letter of each token has $80 added to it.
- The table is terminated by a 00 byte, so the tokenizer can recognize the end when tokenizing.

Here is the code from `LIST` in the Basic ROM which prints out a token (Commodore 64 version): (source: https://www.pagetable.com/c64disasm/#A724 comments from Lee Davison)

The idea here is to start with a pointer (the Y index register) to the beginning of the token table.
Subtract $7F from the token, which leaves the lowest value now at 1 (not 0).
Decrement the token number (X register). If now 0, Y points to the correct token now, and skip ahead to print it.
Else, skip until past the next byte with the $80 bit set and go back.

```
.,A724 38       SEC            else set carry for subtract 
.,A725 E9 7F    SBC #$7F       reduce token range to 1 to whatever 
.,A727 AA       TAX            copy token # to X 
.,A728 84 49    STY $49        save index for line 
.,A72A A0 FF    LDY #$FF       start from -1, adjust for pre increment 
.,A72C CA       DEX            decrement token # 
.,A72D F0 08    BEQ $A737      if now found go do printing 
.,A72F C8       INY            else increment index 
.,A730 B9 9E A0 LDA $A09E,Y    get byte from keyword table 
.,A733 10 FA    BPL $A72F      loop until keyword end marker 
.,A735 30 F5    BMI $A72C      go test if this is required keyword, branch always found keyword, it's the next one
```

So what happens with our 1-too-high token?

Well, our token pointer Y will have skipped past the last valid token text (and Y points at the terminator 00 byte). When decrementing the token number in X we end up at 00, which must mean we're at the right token text, so we decide to print this text. See `A737`.

Note how the `BNE $A737` is marked "branch always". However, with our $00 byte that we just printed, this doesn't actually happen. The "print character" routine at $AB47 helpfully restores the status flags for the just-printed character.

```
                               print keyword

.,A737 C8       INY            increment keyword table index 
.,A738 B9 9E A0 LDA $A09E,Y    get byte from table 
.,A73B 30 B2    BMI $A6EF      go restore index, mask byte and print if byte was end marker 
.,A73D 20 47 AB JSR $AB47      else go print the character
.,A740 D0 F5    BNE $A737      go get next character, branch always
```

So as a result, we fall into the interpreter routine for the FOR keyword. It will try to fetch bytes from the program and interpret them as following a FOR keyword. However, what it gets isn't valid (the relevant pointer is pointing just past the LIST command we just issued), and hence: "?SYNTAX ERROR".

```
                               perform FOR

.,A742 A9 80    LDA #$80       set FNX
.,A744 85 10    STA $10        set subscript/FNX flag
.,A746 20 A5 A9 JSR $A9A5      perform LET
.,A749 20 8A A3 JSR $A38A      search the stack for FOR or GOSUB activity
.,A74C D0 05    BNE $A753      branch if FOR, this variable, not found
                               FOR, this variable, was found so first we dump the old one
.,A74E 8A       TXA
```

Here is the print character routine, shown because it explicitly restores the Zero flag.

```
                               print character

.,AB47 20 0C E1 JSR $E10C      output character to channel with error check
.,AB4A 29 FF    AND #$FF       set the flags on A
.,AB4C 60       RTS
```

Comment: It is also possible that there is a load of assembler code after the **REM L**.  It is something I used quite a lot when I was playing with Commodore PETs in the early 80s.